# Mathjax in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-app, mathjax, content-security-policy

I am trying to use MathJax in Chrome Packaged app.
It is not loading at all giving the following error :

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

How can I make it work?

**EDIT**

IT is showing this line to be the problem in the library

```
var CONSTRUCTOR = function () {
    return new Function ("return arguments.callee.Init.call(this,arguments)");
```

Answer (score 2):

eval and new functions are not permitted in packaged apps, which require a strict set of content security policy. See the documentation [Comply with CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html) for more details.

That page links to a few different solutions, the most likely one being to use [sandboxing](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#sandboxing).